# Scraper (puppeteer) doesn't map over my array - JavaScript / React

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have written a web scraper with puppeteer. It screens jobs from a job portal. I can screen title, position and image.

**The created array from my scraper looks like this:**

```
[{
    "id": "2018-12-03T14:12:03Z",
    "position": "Frontend Entwickler React (w/m)",
    "company": "Muster AG",
    "image": "https://www.stepstone.de/upload_de/logo/blabla.gif",
    "date": "2018-12-03T14:12:03Z",
    "href": "https://www.stepstone.de/stellenangebote--Frontend-Entwickler"
  }]
```

**Here is the code of my scraper.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(
    'https://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?stf=freeText&ns=1&qs=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22231794%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Frontend-Entwickler%2Fin%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22jd%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22300000115%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Deutschland%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22geocity%22%7D%5D&companyID=0&cityID=300000115&sourceOfTheSearchField=homepagemex%3Ageneral&searchOrigin=Homepage_top-search&ke=Frontend-Entwickler%2Fin&ws=Deutschland&ra=30'
  )

  const stepstone = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.job-element'), card => {
      const id = card.querySelector('time').getAttribute('datetime')
      const href = card
        .querySelector('.job-element__body > a')
        .getAttribute('href')
      const position = card
        .querySelector('.job-element__body__title')
        .textContent.trim()
        .replace(/^(.{45}[^\s]*).*/, '$1')
      const company = card
        .querySelector('.job-element__body__company')
        .textContent.trim()
        .replace(/^(.{20}[^\s]*).*/, '$1')
      const image_element = card.querySelector('.job-element__logo img')
      const image = image_element.dataset.src
        ? `https://www.stepstone.de${image_element.dataset.src}`
        : image_element.src
      const date = card.querySelector('time').getAttribute('datetime')

      return {
        id,
        position,
        company,
        image,
        date,
        href
      }
    })
  })

  fs.writeFile(
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/stepstone.json'),
    JSON.stringify(stepstone),
    err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Great, it worked!')
      }
    }
  )

  await browser.close()
})()
```

**My Approach:** After scraping the title, position, etc. I also want to include the job details. So I told my scraper to go to the href link of each job item in the array where this information is stored.

And from that link grab the job details classes just like above. So I tried to map over the above array and tell the scraper to grab the items from each href link, like this:

```
stepstone.map(async stone => {
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(stone.href)
        const details = await page.evaluate(() => {
          return document.querySelector('card__body')
        })
        return {
          ...stone,
          details
        }
      })
```

**My Problem:** 
However, the JSON file does not update with the "details" key (which shall hold information from `'card__body'`).

Any suggestions?
Thx!

Comment: You're returning an element from page.evaluate(). You probably want to return a regular object.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In other words `document.querySelector('card__body')` almost certainly returns undefined, and if it dioesn't, it returns a DOM element which is not what you need in your json output.